# Mutual Equilibrium and Internal Equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, equilibrium

In my textbook, an example where two systems that are subsystems of an isolated supersystem is presented. The two systems are brought together and allowed to exchange energy to reach mutual thermal equilibrium. I attached a figure of the time progression from the time the two systems are separated until they reach mutual thermal equilibrium. I have two questions that have been confusing me and I hope someone can help me answer them:

1. After the two systems are brought together and as they exchange energy to reach mutual thermal equilibrium (not yet at mutual equilibrium: at time $t*$ in the figure), is each subsystem in a state of internal equilibrium even though the two systems have not yet reached mutual thermal equilibrium (equal temperatures)? Is this also true if the exchanged quantity is particles ($N$) and volume ($V$)?
2. The supersystem is isolated, so all of its macroscopic values ($E, V, N, T, U, P, \cdots$) are all constant throughout the process. Does this mean the supersystem is always in a state of equilibrium throughout the process since all of its macroscopic variables are defined throughout the process?

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your textbook is describing the idealization we employ in equilibium thermodynamics in order to deal with non equilibrium states. When two systems in the real world approach equilibrium with each other, they are **not** not internal equilibrium.  Equilibrium thermodynamics cannot handle this problem. Here is the proper way to understand what the book says. In reality when heat transfers from a hot system to a colder one there is a continuous temperature gradient from one system to the other. Equilibrium thermodynamics models this gradient as two separated systems, one at $T_H$ and the other in $T_C$, both in internal equilibrium and both isolated from each other. In going from the hot to the cold system we observe a temperature difference, the "gradient", but each system is in internal equilibrium so that we may calculate its entropy by counting the number of microstates $\Omega$.
2. The supersystem is defined by its total $E$, $V$ and $N$. It is in equilibrium only if all subsuystems have the same $T$ and $P$ (and same chemical potential). Otherwise the supersystem is in a non equilibrium state with a distribution of local temperatures and pressures, just as a real non equilibrium state. If we imagine the supersystem to be made of many smaller subsystems, we may reproduce any temperature gradient. With oune caveat though: in a real system with temperature gradients we have flow of heat, while here we freeze the flow by taking the subsystems to be at uniform temperature.

Comment: For answer #2, if the supersystem is not in equilibrium can we still assume that each microstate of the supersystem is equally likely (i.e does the equal a priori probabilities hold for the microstates of the whole system as the subsystems try to reach mutual equilibrium?

Comment: A very good question. The answer is *yes* – but with a qualification. The number of *accessible* microstates in the super system is $\Omega_{1,2}=\Omega_1\Omega_2$ and they are all equally probable. The super system is in equilibrium when $\Omega_{1,2}$ is maximum, which means that non equilibrium states have access to *fewer* microstates. If we think of these states as *possible* but *inaccessible* due to constraints, their probability is zero. Therefore: the accessible microstates of the super system are equally probable, but the set of all possible microstates under fixed $(E,V,N)$ are not.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand this. So if the supersystem is large, the maximum term method applies. Therefore we can say that the accessible microstates of the supersystem at equilibrium represent the majority of all possible microstates under fixed (E,V,N), so approximately all possible microstates under fixed (E,V,N) are equally likely?

Comment: That's correct. When the super-system is partitioned in an equilibrium way it contains the overwhelming majority of possible microstates. In this case the number of microstates that are excluded due to the presence of internal barriers is an infinitesimal fraction of the total number of microstates.  This is a statement of the maximum term method and  can be easily demonstrated with a simple combinatorial calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome Abe,

1.- The role of time in equilibrium SM is subtle. The answer depends on the protocol you use to put the two subsystems in contact. If the barrier avoiding energetic exchange between the subsystems is removed very slowly (quasistatically), then one can consider that in all moments both subsystems are in thermal equilibrium with different temperatures. If both systems are put suddenly in contact, then there is a fast transient towards equilibrium. This transient cannot be understood as an equilibrium state. Just think that equilibrium states are stationary (there is no time dependence). Any thermodynamic current breaks equilibrium (energy, particles, etc.). The fact is that the quasi-stationary process that I mentioned before  approximate the thermodynamic currents to zero.

2.- I think that the second question is not well stated. If the two subsystems have different temperatures in state A (before letting them exchange energy), then in this state A there is no meaning in saying that the entire system has a total temperature. What you can say is that the Energy is indeed the same in state A and state B (once the subsystems are in thermal equilibrium).